# how to create clean urls and MVC in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I wanted to know that how to create clean urls or MVC in java/jsp? I am learning java and I'd like to develop websites in jsp with clean urls so if anyone knows, please help me.

Comment: What are "*clean urls*"?

Comment: I want to use mysite/login instead of mysite/login.jsp or mysite/register instead of mysite/register.jsp :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map jsp files in web.xml for clean urls as given below.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>yourjsp</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/yourjsp.jsp</jsp-file> // here you can give jsp location
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>yourjsp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/yourjsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanx. And as I said I am learning, do you have suggestions for me to become a pro java programmer?

Comment: Learn and practice, Do some hobby projects , it will help you build your skills.