# JSP not calling ajax function

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I have written an ajax function which will be called when someone selects a year from a dropdown. On selecting the year, the ajax will call a servlet based on passed URL and that servlet will set a value in properties file. However, the problem is, on selecting the year, my ajax block is not called

```
</tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Year</td>
                    <td>
                        <html:select property="yearId" >
                            <html:options collection=
                                    "<%=GlobalValues.LIST_MODELYEAR%>" 
                                    property="id" labelProperty="value" />
                        </html:select>
                        (Required)
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <script>
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $("#yearId").change(function() 
            {

                var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                $.ajax

                ({
                    url : "/ModelByYear.do?cID="+selectedValue+'',



                });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Your jquery function is working?

Comment: Yes. jquery function is working...but not ajax one

Comment: Have you checked that your select element has `id="yearId"`, and used the console to confirm whether there are any javascript errors?

Comment: the problem is in the starting itself. I am not able to call Ajax function on changing the dropdpwn value. Could you please suggest what can be wring while calling the AJAX function?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/`  from your URL as given below and the `,` is not neccesory

```
$.ajax({
         url : "ModelByYear.do?cID="+selectedValue
      });
```

Try by using the below code

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "ModelByYear.do",
  data: {cID:selectedValue},
  success: function(result){
              alert('Result: ' + result);
           },
   error: function(err){
               alert('Error: ' + e);     
          }
     });
```

- **type** is html request type you can use GET or POST
- **ModelByYear.do** is URL in you case you must map this url-pattern in `WEB.xml`

While working on JSP's don't call jsp pages directly instead configure in WEB.xml as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103824/how-to-create-clean-urls-and-mvc-in-jsp/24103857#24103857)

Comment: tried with the above code. But doesnt seems to be working.I am mapping the url with the servlet sing struts config

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: Basically it is not at all calling the AJAX function after selecting a value from the dropdown.

Comment: Better check browser console, check the given URL is working or not, call that URL from browser directly once and check

Comment: the problem is in the starting itself. I am not able to call Ajax function on changing the dropdpwn value. Could you please suggest what can be wring while calling the AJAX function?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the url you build first before calling the AJAX?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $("#yearId").change(function() 
            {
                var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                window.location = "/ModelByYear.do?cID="+selectedValue;
            });
        });
```

Comment: the problem is in the starting itself. I am not able to call Ajax function on changing the dropdpwn value. Could you please suggest what can be wring while calling the AJAX function?